# Get child input element value update

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML code as follows:

```
<div id="input2" class="clonedInput">
    <div class="col-sm-3 text_flied">
        <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">
            <input type="" class="bwidth" value="" placeholder="300" name="fr_width[1]">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 text_middle no-padding">
            <p>X</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 no-padding">
            <input type="" class=" bheight" value="" placeholder="300" name="fr_height[1]">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to update the value of the input field `fr_width[1]`. This sections are dynamically created as `fr_width[2]`, `fr_width[3]` and so on.

To update the value, I use the following code, but it is not working. I tried the `children()` option too.

```
$("#input2").siblings(".col-sm-4 input").val('123');

$("#input2").closest(".bwidth").val('123');
```

Both ways are not working.

Comment: use find() instead of siblings()...

Comment: if both input value is same then :) `$("#input2").find(".col-sm-4 input").val('123');` should work fine.

Comment: @ C-link Nepal: I tried this. Its update the value. But 2 fields are updated. Here there are 2 text fields and 2 div are in the class name of col-sm-4. by using this both input field are  updated? (fr_width[1]  or fr_height[1])?

Comment: Or `$('#input2 .col-sm-4 input').val('123')`. Why use `.find()` at all, in this case? Just put them together in one selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3ck5sxc9/)** :-

```
   $("#input2").find(".text_flied").find(".bwidth").val('123');
```

**OR**

```
   $("#input2").children(".text_flied").find(".bwidth").val('123');
```

**OR**

```
   $("#input2").find(".bwidth").val('123');
```

**OR**

The shortest way you can go for

```
    $("#input2 .bwidth").val('123');
```

1)- `closest` only works for ancestor or the selector itself .

2)- `siblings` only works for the **same heirarchy nodes.**

There are lots of ways you can find your `required selector` and set `value` to it .

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation on jQuery's [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

- Siblings is for getting the elements on the **same** DOM level as the selector, in this case `#input2`, and not its children
- Closest is for getting the closest **parent** element of `#input2`, up in the DOM tree

What you want is simply:

```
$('#input2 input.bwidth').val('123')
```

to update the `.bwidth` input under `#input2` only. If there are more, then `$('input.bwidth').val('123')` should update all inputs with the class name `bwidth`.

Here is a reference on how [jQuery's selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) work.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use something like this. If you want to get specific item dynamically.

```
 var itemIndex = 1;   
 $("input[name='fr_width["+itemIndex +"]']").val("123")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so difficult? Just select all inputfields within div with id "input2". So you can choose the inputfield from the returned array.

**Example:**

```
    $('#input2 input').eq(0).val("123");
```